# how to identify which apps script is connected to the Google sheets - the person left company, we're trying to run BOT

Tags: google-apps-script

The "Bot" consist of a JS code that was using google sheets to send automated emails using a database in google sheets, I have access to the google sheets.. and the leads, but can't find the Apps Script that was tying all together. Is there a way to know where is that link from the existing links? She left the company, and we may think she deleted the files.

I just have to report to the owner if any of what she build has any value.. I'm just a developer on another area of the company - helping out here, but I'm lost.

Can anyone please guide me.. or provide resources to identify where is the JS code that ran sequence?

Thanks!

Comment: Probably you can see the script in this list: https://myaccount.google.com/permissions?pli=1

Comment: All _your_ scripts are here: https://script.google.com/home/all But I don't know how a script can be identified there. Probably it's need to read them all and figure out. If you're lucky the script will have a name "Bot"

Comment: Thanks, for this I would have to access her Google account right?

Comment: First link doesn't need access. There are all scripts (yours and someone's) that have access to your account. Second link does. There are all scripts of a given (logged in) account.

Comment: Ok, I'm asking IT for her google account.  Thank you sooo much Yuri

Answer (score 1):

You will need to navigate to tools > script editor in the google sheets where these scripts are running.

[This is the dropdown menu you are looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfseL.png)

The scripts will show up in the "files" section when the script editor opens. Based on your description of the Bot you describe you should also be able to login to https://console.cloud.google.com/ and view the project. Your employee may have deleted the files in question or it may just be a billing issue where your Google Cloud account has gone delinquent.

Comment: Thanks! I tried this and there are no existing scripts - I believe she deleted them.. she asked for more money to the company and walked out.. but believed she deleted it the main jS

Comment: Under the Google cloud platform still didn't find anything..

Comment: There are 'stand-alone' scripts as well. They exist outside 'containers' (docs, spreadsheets, etc).

Comment: Do I need to access her Google account to see anything using the links you provided?

Comment: Thank you soo much Same -- i will check with IT for her google account and see if I can startup the bot.. as all of this is new to me.

Comment: Yes, you would need access to her google account if the documents/scripts weren't shared with another user. Otherwise you would need edit permissions to any documents or folders where they might be located. You should also be able to check edit history to see if she did delete items recently.